# How do you make a google map centered at an address with a certain label?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Let's say I wanted to integrate into my website a google map.  I want it to be centered on my home (which I have the address for, not its exact latitude and longitude).  I want a custom marker pointing to my house that says, "My house".

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question is too broad, but you can get stated by looking at this example from the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: How is it broad?  It is very specific.  The only detail I withheld is what my address is.

Comment: Because the question as it stands is basically "how to use geolocation service" and "how to add a marker". Both are too broad for this site, and each topic could be answered with an extensive tutorial (which Google already provide). The question would fit the site if you provided code you already tried and pinpoint specific problems in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself made a website where people can see different places on the map with historical detail. It is quite easy simply go to https://maps.google.com/ then press the MY PLACES tab on the top-left hand side. Sign in and then press the create map button or click the link (below it) to set your Home or Business location. Add custom or default markers and that's it. Finally save and press the chain button (at the start menu) and get the iframe or short url NO coding required...Easy to use! Hope that helped @Joe ^_^   Oh and @bfavaretto don't be like that...